# Pandas how to display pivoted values UNDER columns

Tags: pandas

I need the below but with USD and EU under each of Bronze, Gold and Silver.  How?

[image]

Edit - My question is different because I want the columns ABOVE the values.

Comment: See Question 6 in the dup: `df.pivot_table(index='Item', columns='CType', values=['USD', 'EU'], aggfunc='first')`

Comment: Please see my edit.  I am not wanting it to look like the screenshot but with the USD and EU under the Bronze, Gold and Silver

Comment: Then assign the above to some variable (say `df1`) then do `df1 = df1.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`. I updated the duplicate list to include that.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!